# IOS tap UILabel in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I am trying to create a view which is similar to Facebook's home view which has multiple tap-able areas.

Everything is done (though I don't know if I am following the correct way for this atm) but the alignment of the view is incorrect. The data is coming on different rows as [image]. What I really want to achieve is [image]

I am displaying my data in `UITableView`.

I have tried this code of snippet:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
RequestInfo *requestInfo = [self.myDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSArray *localizedStringPieces = [requestInfo.feed componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
NSUInteger msgChunkCount = localizedStringPieces ? localizedStringPieces.count : 0;

CGPoint wordLocation = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < msgChunkCount; i++)
{

    NSString *chunk = [localizedStringPieces objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([chunk isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        continue;
    }
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0f];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;

    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.cellView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(280, FLT_MAX);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [chunk sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];



    //adjust the label the the new height.
    CGRect newFrame = label.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
    label.frame = newFrame;
        if ([[identifireArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] count]> 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < [[identifireArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] count]; i++) {
            if ([chunk hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",[[identifireArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:i]]]) {
                label.text = chunk;
                label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:110/255.0f green:181/255.0f blue:229/255.0f alpha:1.0];
                label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
                label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureAction:)];
                [label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
                label.text = [label.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",[[identifireArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:i]] withString:@""];


                break;
            } else {
                label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                label.text = chunk;
                label.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
             }
        }
    }

    [label sizeToFit];

    if (cell.cellView.frame.size.width < wordLocation.x + label.bounds.size.width)
    {
        wordLocation.x = 0.0;                       // move this word all the way to the left...
        wordLocation.y += label.frame.size.height;  // ...on the next line


        NSRange startingWhiteSpaceRange = [label.text rangeOfString:@"^\\s*"
                                                            options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
        if (startingWhiteSpaceRange.location == 0)
        {
            label.text = [label.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:startingWhiteSpaceRange
                                                             withString:@""];
            [label sizeToFit];
        }
    }

    // Set the location for this label:
    label.frame = CGRectMake(wordLocation.x,
                             wordLocation.y,
                             label.frame.size.width,
                             label.frame.size.height);



    [cell.cellView addSubview:label];

    // Update the horizontal position for the next word:
    wordLocation.x += label.frame.size.width;



};


return cell;
```

}

Here is the sample source text that I am using:

```
#(team)Team_Football_Test# won the football match #(event)testing football# against #(team)Bengal Tigers Football Club(DG Testing)#
#(team)Team_crick_Test# won the football match #(event)C4 cricket# against #(team)Bengal Tigers Cricket Club(DG Testing)#
```

When I split the string and add it to a UILabel, I can't align it properly. I want the look n feel same like Facebook wall page where all the data is properly aligned but my view is misaligned. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add a screenshot of what you get and what you want

Comment: You can also have a cell reuse problem as you keep adding more subviews all the time

Comment: Here is the [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oOyUx.png) .But  I want this type of [display](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g2r73.png) .

Comment: @Wain Here is my current [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oOyUx.png). But I want this type of [output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g2r73.png).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple labels, and don't create new labels and add as subviews in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

So, first, create a custom cell subclass which adds your label and any other views and lays the views out in the correct places (and resizes them).

For the label contents, use `attributedText` instead of `text` and use the 'chunk' information to apply the attributed formatting to the text in the label (instead of creating multiple different labels).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Wain.

Create custom cell and add all your labels, images and any default formatting.

User interface builder to visually create all these. This will make your life much easier.